# check permission against group not users using Auth->authorize="actions"

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-1.3, authorize

Can any one explain me the working of `Auth->authorize = "actions"`
In my project i am planning tp give this.
As [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/396/authorize) taught me the authorize will call the `$this->Aro->check($user,"controllers/:controller/:action")`

This will check the against the user right??
that means the user should be there in aros table.
But i don't need this to check against user but i need to check against a group
How can i achive this.

now when the users is not in Aro table it showing the

So that The Aro's will be only the groups and adding of users to the Aros is needed

thankz in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution
using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677532/cakephp-auth-component-using-2-tables/1701826#1701826)
i extended the AuthComponent to CustomAuth and overridden the `isAutorized()` method in the AuthComponent as follows

in controllers/components/custom_auth.php

```
    <?php
App::import('Component','Auth');
class CustomAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {

    public function isAuthorized($type = null, $object = null, $user = null) {

        $actions  = $this->__authType($type);
        if( $actions['type'] != 'actions' ){
            return parent::isAuthorized($type, $object, $user);
        }
        if (empty($user) && !$this->user()) {
            return false;
        } elseif (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->user();
        }


        $group = array('model' => 'Group','foreign_key' =>$user['Login']['group_id']);
        $valid = $this->Acl->check($group, $this->action());
        return $valid;
    }
}
?>
```

in app_controller.php

```
function beforeFilter()
{
$this->CustomAuth->userModel = 'Login';
$this->CustomAuth->allowedActions = array('display');
$this->CustomAuth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
$this->CustomAuth->authorize = 'actions';
}
```

This solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/471/Checking-Permissions-The-ACL-Component). To check a group permission do this ('model' and 'foreign_key' values are from aros table):

```
$this->Acl->check(
     array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),
    'controller/action'
);
```

Comment: but since Auth->authorize = "actions" is given the checking will be done automaticly right?

Comment: That's right. You will need to use `$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';` and `isAuthorized()` method (http://book.cakephp.org/view/396/authorize).

Comment: but if am giving `$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';` i need to goto every controller and override `isAuthorized()`. How can i avoid this overriding in every controller??

Comment: then also i need to call the `isAuthorized()` from every controller
Already tried and failed