# How to give node referance to check cakephp 2.3 ACL permission

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, user-permissions, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp 2.3.0 and working with ACL. I am giving the permission to a group as follows:

```
$group->id = 2;
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts');
```

Now how can I check 'controllers/Posts' is allowed for $group->id = 2 from same controller?

I am trying

```
$this->Acl->check('controllers/Posts', '2');
```

but it always return false and generate warning:

```
Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
Aro: controllers/Pages
Aco: Data entry operator
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Syntax**

```
$this->Acl->check(array(
    'model' => 'ModelName',       # The name of the Model to check agains
    'foreign_key' => $foreign_key # The foreign key the Model is bind to
), 'Controller/action');          # The controller and action to check the permissions for
```

Which results in the following call:

*As a User*

```
$this->Acl->check(array(
    'model' => 'User',
    'foreign_key' => $userId
), 'Posts/index');
```

*As a Group*

```
$this->Acl->check(array(
    'model' => 'Group',
    'foreign_key' => $groupId
), 'Posts/index');
```

*I wrote it down including some linebreaks for readability.*

**More info at:**

- http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AclComponent.html#_check
- http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AclNode.html
- [check permission against group not users using Auth->authorize="actions"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413747/1110760)

Comment: One more question, $this->Acl->check() is very slow. takes too long to check all the resource. Has there any way faster way?

Comment: You could cache every unique entry in an array in you Session. That way you don't have to check it several times. Just extend the AuthComponent and add a new method which tries to check the session data first. *Note: when you updated the ACL table and the user didn't destroy it's session, I won't be known by the session, just keep that in mind ;-)* But no, there aren't any faster ways other than caching. Sad enough. But generally the ACL tables doesn't get changed that often.

Answer (score 0):

checking a node permission is very similar to setting that permission ie

```
$group->id = 2;
 $this->Acl->check($group, 'controllers/Posts');
```